# ElasticSearch Java High Level REST Client: filter documents and or query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to retrieve documments filtered by "brand" attribute, and retrieve those that have an specic value for another attribute. Example:

All "apple" documents ("brand" attribute) that are active ("active" attribute true), with id "abc" , "def" or "ghi" values.

I am using Java High Level REST Client.

That is my code:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
  searchRequest.types(type);

  SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

  /* add query filters */
  MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("brand", brand);
  searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);

  /* base sort is added */
  //TODO: load sort from mapping based on baseSort of customSort
  searchSourceBuilder.sort(sortBy , SortOrder.DESC);

  /* add product id */

  BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
          .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("active", true));

  searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
  searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: i can help you with this please provide some information

Comment: can you reply what you trying to do here

Comment: I need to do an in query filtering by several attributes: Example: Documents where brand is "HP", active is true, and order_id is "ABC" or "DEF" o "GHI"

Comment: ok that not a problem

Comment: can you share you mapping

Comment: Mapping is too big, and I thing the example is enough, do you really need it? In MongoDB, and also in Oracle it is a very simple query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX);
        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(searchText + "*").defaultField("companyName")
                .defaultOperator(Operator.AND);

SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("categories.id", category)
            .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("product_id", productIdsList)
           );



sourceBuilder.sort(new ScoreSortBuilder().order(SortOrder.DESC));
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
```

Comment: Hi, at the end I was able to solve it using a bool should query with an array of values. BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("categories.id", category)
      .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("product_id", productIdsList));